# PHP define array with sub arrays as an index

Tags: php, arrays, sub-array

I am using a PHP file to define some data to be used in another app.

I thought this was a valid way to declare my arrays.. with sub-arrays as indexes.

But apparently not..

```
//question 1
$quiz['question'][0] = "xxx";
$quiz['question'][0]['answer'][0] = "xxx";
$quiz['question'][0]['answer'][1] = "xxx";
$quiz['question'][0]['answer'][2] = "xxx";
$quiz['question'][0]['answer'][3] = "xxx";
$quiz['question'][0]['answer'][4] = "xxx";
```

How do I correctly define these are easily/legible arrays?

I am currently getting this error/warning:

**Warning: Illegal string offset 'answer'**

Comment: why would you expect an array === a string?

Comment: What did you want to achieve with this code? It is clear why it doesn't work, but it is not clear why did you want it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are explicitly saying in the first line that `$quiz['question'][0]` is a string, and afterwards you try to act as if its an array, thats why you are getting this error

Comment: DOH!..  you are totally correct!  it should have been:  $quiz['question'][0]['question']

Thank you for staying on topic and posting my error  (accepted)

Answer (score 1):

How to define, well one way

```
$quiz['question'][0]['question'] = "How to define an array";
$quiz['question'][0]['answer'][0] = "Like this";
$quiz['question'][0]['answer'][1] = "or like that";
$quiz['question'][0]['answer'][2] = "or maybe like the other";
print_r($quiz);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [question] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [question] => How to define an array
                    [answer] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Is it like this
                            [1] => Or isit like that
                            [2] => Or is it like the other
                        )

                )

        )

)
```